# Is it possible to have deployment slots with different service plans in Azure WebApps?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I've worked a lot in the past with Azure Cloud Services Web Roles, but I am a bit new with Azure Websites/WebApps.  I really loved the concept of multiple deployment slots you could define for WebApps, that enables some useful CD scenarios. In my case, I will have Test->PreProd->Prod slots defined. All good!

Is it possible to specify different pricing tiers or number of instances for each of those environments? They seem to share the pricing tier of the service plan. 
Is it possible to define a different number of instances for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Multiple deployment slots are only available in Standard SKU (the highest one): http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

So, no. What you require is not possible.

You can however mitigate that by not using the staged publishing. You can instead, have different service plans with different web apps. You can then link each of the web apps to a different branch of your repository (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/). Thus when you push to your UAT branch - you get deployment in UAT web site. When you push to your Relese branch, you get deployment to your Releas web site and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I just managed to set the Production (default) slot and a Test slot on different App Service Plans. Just click the "..." on the description blade for the Web App/Slot and select the "Change App service plan" option..

Answer (score 1):

When you create a site in the standard plan,  you're basically paying for the VM and you can put as many sites as the VM can handle on it.

This means that you get all the slots for your site in the Standard SKU for free.

Comment: When yous scale up the number of instances, you also scale the deployment slots too right?

Comment: @TWilly If you mean that your deployment slot (eg. site-dev) gets extra instances, then yes.